# Derivation of Simspon's 1/3 rule using lagrange polynomial

Tags: calculus, interpolation

Taking the Lagrange interpolation formular for a second order polynomial
$$f_2(x)=L_0(x)f(x_0)+L_1(x)f(x_1)+L_2(x)f(x_2)$$
Where $$\begin{align}L_0(x)&=\frac{(x-x_1)(x-x_2)}{(x_0-x_1)(x_0-x_2)}\\L_1(x)&=\frac{(x-x_0)(x-x_2)}{(x_1-x_0)(x_1-x_2)}\\L_2(x)&=\frac{(x-x_0)(x-x_1)}{(x_2-x_0)(x_2-x_1)}\end{align}$$
Therefore,
$$f_2(x)=\frac{(x-x_1)(x-x_2)}{(x_0-x_1)(x_0-x_2)}f(x_0)+\frac{(x-x_0)(x-x_2)}{(x_1-x_0)(x_1-x_2)}f(x_1)+\frac{(x-x_0)(x-x_1)}{(x_2-x_0)(x_2-x_1)}f(x_2)$$
The area of $f(x)$ under the interval $[x_0,x_2]$ is given by
$$\begin{align}\int_{x_0}^{x_2}f(x)dx&\approx\int_{x_0}^{x_2}\left[L_0(x)f(x_0)+L_1(x)f(x_1)+L_2(x)f(x_2)\right]dx\\\int_{x_0}^{x_2}f(x)dx&\approx\left[\frac{(x-x_1)(x-x_2)}{(x_0-x_1)(x_0-x_2)}f(x_0)+\frac{(x-x_0)(x-x_2)}{(x_1-x_0)(x_1-x_2)}f(x_1)+\frac{(x-x_0)(x-x_1)}{(x_2-x_0)(x_2-x_1)}f(x_2)\right]dx\end{align}$$

After integrating I reached this$$\int_{x_0}^{x_2}f(x)dx\approx\left[\frac{\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^2(x_2+x_1)}{2}+(x_1x_2)x}{(x_0-x_1)(x_0-x_2)}f(x_0)+\frac{\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^2(x_2+x_0)}{2}+(x_0x_2)x}{(x_1-x_0)(x_1-x_2)}f(x_1)+\frac{\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^2(x_0+x_1)}{2}+(x_1x_0)x}{(x_2-x_1)(x_2-x_0)}f(x_2)\right]$$ but after this I am unable to get the answer.
Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Please explain or give a reference to the Simpson 1/3 rule. You cannot expect that everybody knows it.

Answer (score 1):

The Wikipedia article on [Simpson's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule) also gives your deviation, but suppresses the calculations that you could not master. Maybe you forgot to input that $x_0=a$, $x_1={1\over2}(a+b)$, $x_2=b$.

At any rate I would suggest to use another approach. We may assume $x_0=-1$, $x_1=0$, $x_2=1$ and verify easily that Simpson's rule gives the correct integral values for the three parabolas $y=ax^2+bx+c$ having $y=1$ at one of the three points and $y=0$ at the  other two points. This and the "linearity of everything" proves your claim.